# how do i remove style from other than img tag in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I want to remove style from all html tags but not from img tag in javascript.

I am using like this ..

```
content.replace(/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/g, '$1');
```

but it replace style from all the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
content.replace(/(<(?!img)[^>]+) style=".*?"/g, '$1');
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like that should do the trick as a javascript solution

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('*'),
    len = els.length,
    i = 0;

for (; i < len; i++) {
  if (els[i].nodeName.toUpperCase() !== 'IMG') {
    els[i].removeAttribute('style');
  }
}
```

Here is a demo on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FnAEt/